# Prove that the area of any regular polygon of side length $s$ must include $s^2$ in it.

Tags: geometry

I am wondering if it is always the case that the area of any regular polygon of side length $s$ must include $s^2$ in it. Obviously for a square and hexagon it holds (area of square: $s^2$; area of hexagon: $\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}s^2$), but is it always true?

Comment: If you think in terms of dimensions, area of any figure must have terms that are related to product of lengths. Since in regular polygons all lengths are given in terms of side length, therefore having a square term is warranted.

Comment: Hint: Any polygon can be divided into triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a regular $n$-gon with side length $s.$ By drawing segments from each vertex to the center of the $n$-gon, one splits the $n$-gon onto $n$ congruent isosceles triangles with a base of $b=s$, where the angle opposite the base is $2\pi/n$ radians (*i.e.*: one $n$th of $360^\circ$). Some trigonometry shows that the height of each triangle is $$h=\cfrac{\frac12s}{\tan\left(\frac\pi n\right)}=\frac1{2\tan\left(\frac\pi n\right)}s,$$ so the area of each triangle is $$\frac12bh=\frac1{4\tan\left(\frac\pi n\right)}s^2,$$ and so the total area is $$\frac{n}{4\tan\left(\frac\pi n\right)}s^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the formula for the area must be of the form $c\cdot s^2$ for some constant $s$? In that case, the answer is yes. Say that the regular polygon with side length $1$ has area $c$. Since area is $2$-dimensional, area scales by the square of the side length. So the regular polygon with side length $s$ will have area $c\cdot s^2$. Finding the constant $c$ is another question, but it can be found using trigonometry.

To see why the area scales with the square of the side-length, imagine dividing the $n$-gon into $n$ congruent isosceles triangles by drawing lines from the center of the $n$-gon to the vertices. Now these triangles have base $s$, and the angle opposite the base is $\theta=2\pi/n$ radians or $360/n$ degrees. To find the height $h$ of this triangle, drop a perpendicular from the vertex opposite the base to the base. This bisects the angle $\theta$, so now we have two congruent right triangles. One leg has length $\frac{s}{2}$, the other leg has length $h$, and the angle opposite the leg of length $\frac{s}{2}$ is $\theta/2=\pi/n$ radians or $180/n$ degrees. Thus $\tan(\theta/2) = \frac{s/2}{h}$, and $h=\frac{s/2}{\tan(\theta/2)}$. So the area of each isosceles triangle (using $\text{Area}=\frac{1}{2}(\text{base})(\text{height})$) is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot s\cdot \frac{s/2}{\tan(\pi/n)}= \frac{1}{4\tan(\pi/n)} s^2$. Hence the area of the $n$-gon is $\frac{n}{4\tan(\pi/n)} s^2$. This tells you the constant $c$ from above is $\frac{n}{4\tan(\pi/n)}$.

More generally, area always scales with the square of a linear scale factor. To see this for more general shapes you need to get into the calculus of measuring area.

Comment: "Since area is $2$-dimensional, area scales by the square of the side length." This is essentially what OP wants you to prove.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is actually looking for a proof of this fact, rather a verification that it is true.

Comment: @kccu Yes, could you prove that? Or is that what SchrodingersCat did?

Comment: Sure I'll add a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is always true.

Since the basic feature that can be known about any regular polygon can be expressed in terms of the side-length $s$, as you have mentioned, the expression for area of the polygon can be written in terms of $s$ and other real numbers.

But the physical quantity "area" has a dimension of $M^0L^2T^0$ i.e. $L^2$ or in other words, product of $2$ lengths. Hence the area can be represented as some number times $s^2$ for all regular polygons.